# Firefox automation script

Tags: bash, scripting, firefox, mozilla

Some terminals need to be able to automaticaly start Mozilla (or another browser if more convenient) and visit a prespecified page. How is it possible to write a script that runs localy and when invoked it fires up the browser and visits the page? This does not need to be overly complicated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`firefox www.google.com`

When that "script" is invoked, Firefox will open up and head off to Google.